# Animated film where spaceship crew is being killed by a disease; red "berries" on a wall

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

This was an old animated movie, probably made in the late 1990s. I think it was a lot like Japanese anime.

It was based in space (on a spaceship) and I think the crew is being killed by some disease.

I don't remember the crew, I just remember a guy in advanced space suit like one in *Dead Space* (PS3 game), I don't know where they were going. The only "symptoms" I remember are heavy breathing and limping; like he was wounded or something so I think it was meant for adults.

I have a picture in my head of red space "berries" on a wall in one scene. I remember just one scene in which there are some old rusty spaceship doors and the berries grew on it; the whole spaceship had rusty and dusty colour tone, I don't know if they had a purpose.

I had it recorded on a VCR and I think it was dubbed in my native language so no info on that.

Comment: What was the style of animation? Were the crew adults or teens? Were the crew military or civilian? Where were they going? What symptoms did the disease have? Was this a film for kids or adults (e.g. were the deaths depicted graphically)? Were there any notable actors? What did the spaceship look like? What were the berries used for? What were the names of the crew? What was the name of the ship?

Comment: Where did you watch it? What languages was it in?

Comment: I think it was a lot like japanese anime,i don't remember the crew i just remember a guy in advanced space suit like one in deadspace(ps3 game),i don't know where were they going. The only "symptoms" i remember are heavy breathing and limping; like he was wounded or something so i think it was meant for adults. I remember just one scene in which there are some old rusty spaceship doors and the berries grew on it;the whole spaceship had rusty and dusty colour tone ,i don't know if they had a purpose.I had it recorded on a VCR and i think it was dubbed in my native language so no info on that :/

Comment: I am also searcing for this cartoon. I remember the egzact same thing. I also remember one of the crew was a fat curly boy that was alwas causing trouble on the ship. I think the cartoon is called Space odyssay but I can't find any record of it online.... lil bit pissed baha

Comment: OMG...  i searched for it for like 15 years :SSSS    THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 5):

We have found it . The title of the anime is "They were 11" (1986).

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1901/11-nin_Iru):

> The elite Cosmo Academy attracts applicants from every stellar nation in the galaxy. One young hopeful is Tadatos Lane, an orphan esper from Terra. The final stage of the academy's entrance exam is a perilous mission simulation aboard an actual derelict starship. The applicants depart for the ships in groups of ten, but when Tada's crew arrives on the Esperanza, they are horrified to discover that they now number eleven. As the test progresses, things go awry and the atmosphere grows increasingly tense. The crew members begin to suspect sabotage, and Tada appears to be the likely culprit.

[This Amazon review](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3L256HQJQC61X/) mentions a "deadly disease":

> As mentioned above, ten space cadets are sent to a derelict ship floating in space, where they must survive for the next couple months without outside help. Additionally, **the ship is riddled with about-to-explode bombs, infected with a deadly disease**, and is in a slowly-decaying orbit. I wonder how many people die during these tests.